# Problem with using non-negative linear fit with SciPy

Tags: python, scipy, regression

Been trying to use a [non-negative linear fit with SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.nnls.html). But my input doesn´t seem to be correct.

I tried using the fit with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import nnls 

A = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])  
b = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]) 

x, rnorm = nnls(A,b)

print (x, rnorm)
```

I was expecting to get the k- and m-value, but I instead get the following error message:

```
ValueError: expected matrix
```

I think that it might be that this tool requires me to do a linear regression prior to using this non-negative linear fit? But I don´t really understand why. Could anyone help me understand what I´m not understanding with this tool?

Comment: *"I was expecting to get the k- and m-value..."* `nnls` does not do linear regression.  Take another look at the [docstring](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.nnls.html). It finds the least-squares nonnegative solution to the matrix equation Ax=b.

Comment: Ok, so what is the difference between what this tool is doing and a linear regression?